# Where to find list of possible arguments for ethtool -K?

Tags: linux, ethernet, intel, ethtool

When I want to disable/enable interface features with the `ethtool -K` command, how can I list all available options? When I run `ethtool -k` I see a list of options, but I don't know the equivalent `ethtool -K` name for each one.

My man page shows the following:

```
       -K --features --offload
              Changes the offload parameters and other features of the specified network device.  The following feature names are built-in and others may be defined by the kernel.

           rx on|off
                  Specifies whether RX checksumming should be enabled.

           tx on|off
                  Specifies whether TX checksumming should be enabled.

           sg on|off
                  Specifies whether scatter-gather should be enabled.

           tso on|off
                  Specifies whether TCP segmentation offload should be enabled.

           ufo on|off
                  Specifies whether UDP fragmentation offload should be enabled

           gso on|off
                  Specifies whether generic segmentation offload should be enabled

           gro on|off
                  Specifies whether generic receive offload should be enabled

           lro on|off
                  Specifies whether large receive offload should be enabled

           rxvlan on|off
                  Specifies whether RX VLAN acceleration should be enabled

           txvlan on|off
                  Specifies whether TX VLAN acceleration should be enabled

           ntuple on|off
                  Specifies whether Rx ntuple filters and actions should be enabled

           rxhash on|off
                  Specifies whether receive hashing offload should be enabled
```

When I disabled all of these options, and run `ethtool -k` I see there are still a few which are not disabled. Where do I find the `ethtool -K` option for each of these?

```
# ethtool -k enp3s0f0 | grep -v fixed
Features for enp3s0f0:
rx-checksumming: off
tx-checksumming: off
        tx-checksum-ip-generic: off
        tx-checksum-sctp: off
scatter-gather: off
        tx-scatter-gather: off
tcp-segmentation-offload: off
        tx-tcp-segmentation: off
        tx-tcp-mangleid-segmentation: off
        tx-tcp6-segmentation: off
generic-segmentation-offload: off
generic-receive-offload: off
rx-vlan-offload: off
tx-vlan-offload: off
ntuple-filters: off
receive-hashing: off
tx-gre-segmentation: on
tx-gre-csum-segmentation: on
tx-ipxip4-segmentation: on
tx-ipxip6-segmentation: on
tx-udp_tnl-segmentation: on
tx-udp_tnl-csum-segmentation: on
tx-gso-partial: on
tx-nocache-copy: off
rx-all: off
hw-tc-offload: on
```

The system is Fedora Core 30 on kernel `5.2.13-200.fc30.x86_64` and the NIC is an Intel I350.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the long names, i.e. `ethtool -K` also understands the long names you see in the `ethtool -k` output.

For example, the following two calls are equivalent:

```
ethtool -K eno1 sg on
ethtool -K eno1 scatter-gather off
```